# ADFS not responding to HTTP HEAD Request

Tags: adfs, adfs2.0, sap-fiori

We have `ADFS` integrated to `SAP FIORI`. `Fiori Client` in Andoid devices sends a `HTTP HEAD` request to the `ADFS` url, to validate it. But, `ADFS` is not responding to `HEAD` request . Can we implement it anyways ?

Comment: I meant , can we make ADFS respond to a HEAD request?

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but for anyone else hitting this issue, ADFS does not support HEAD requests.
See [Microsoft's Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/overview/ad-fs-faq#does-ad-fs-support-head-requests).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to send the `HTTP HEAD` request from a desktop browser using a `Rest Client` to analyze the issue.